# why isn't a style being applied to this php variable?

Tags: php, css, variable-assignment

I've tried to various solutions to this problem, but nothing seems to be working. I know the stylesheet is kicking in, because other rules are in place.

**EDIT**
the .error style is attached but i'm now getting two echos of $error, one in red and one in black one line below it. the reference to rcheader contains no references to $error.

css:

```
.error{
color:#FF0000;
}
```

This is the entire php page:

```
<link type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" />
<?php // rclogin.php
include_once 'rcheader.php';
echo "<h3>Member Log in</h3>";
// $error="<span class='error'></span>";
$error = $user = $pass = "";

if (isset($_POST['user']))
{
    $user = sanitizeString($_POST['user']);
    $pass = sanitizeString($_POST['pass']);

    if ($user == "" || $pass == "")
    {
        $error = 'Not all fields were entered correctly.<br />';
    }
if(strlen($error)>0) {
    echo '<span class="error">' . $error . '</span><br/>';
}
    else
    {
        $query = "SELECT user,pass FROM rcmembers
                  WHERE user='$user' AND pass='$pass'";

        if (mysql_num_rows(queryMysql($query)) == 0)
        {
            $error = "Username/Password invalid<br />";
        }
        else
        {
            $_SESSION['user'] = $user;
            $_SESSION['pass'] = $pass;
            die("You are now logged in. Please
               <a href='rcmembers.php?view=$user'>click here</a>.");
        }
    }
}

echo <<<_END
<form method='post' action='rclogin.php'>$error
Username <input type='text' maxlength='16' name='user'
    value='$user' /><br />
Password <input type='password' maxlength='16' name='pass'
    value='$pass' /><br />
&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
<input type='submit' value='Login' />
</form>
_END;
?>
```

Comment: Have you inspected the element with FireBug (for FF) or Developer tools (F12)?

Comment: Styles aren't applied to PHP variables, they're applied to HTML elements, and HTML elements are sometimes generated by PHP. Decide whether your problem is the HTML generation or the styling. If the problem is styling, show us the HTML that gets sent to the browser

Comment: You're assigning a new value to `$error` at the (current) end of the code. Can you show more lines?

Comment: Are you defining style for you span class="error" some place else ? because maybe it's override the one you're trying to set.

Comment: it doesn't have a rule applied to it...so every declaration that gets called would strip the style if it was applied?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The logic of your php code is the problem here:

```
$error = $user = $pass = "";

if ($error) {
   echo '<span class="error">' . $error . '</span><br/>';
}
```

You set the error message to be an empty string, and then you immediately have it spit out an empty error message, and THEN you run the check that populated the `$error` variable?!?

Remove

```
if ($error) {
    echo '<span class="error">' . $error . '</span><br/>';
}
```

And modify this code to add the error-output logic:

```
if ($user == "" || $pass == "") {
    $error = 'Not all fields were entered.<br />';
}
if(strlen($error)>0) {
    echo '<span class="error">' . $error . '</span><br/>';
}
```

** Keep in mind... ** when checking if a variable is an empty string, use `strlen($var)==0` or `empty($var)` or check if `$var==''` the statement: `if($var)` is looking for a boolean TRUE/FALSE

Comment: this outputs a styled and unstyled version of the error message? what does the . $variable . syntax do exactly?

Comment: `.` is the concatenation operator. Its job is to join strings together (so `$string = 'my string'; echo 'which string? '.$string;` will spit out 'which string? my string'. On the double outputting, did you remove the initial `if($error)` statement? If so, and it's still happening, could you post more code + the output?

Comment: This is because you're still printing the error message twice, only the second time you don't have it wrapped in `<span class='error'></span>` tags. The first time is: `echo '<span class="error">' . $error . '</span><br/>';` -  this means "Print this to the page" and this is being styled correctly. But then you have it spit it out again here: `<form method='post' action='rclogin.php'>$error`. In this second case it has no styling. Either remove the second `$error` reference OR remove the first one and set `$error = "<span class='error'>$error</span>";` before you enter the <<<END block

Comment: No. the second one displays inside the form, but if you don't care whether it exists inside or outside the form element then just remove the second one.

Answer (score 2):

The most likely answer is that another CSS file defines a style for the .error class that is more specific than the one you mention here.

Change your css to

```
    span.error {
    color: #FF0000 !important;
}
```

Edit: @PeeHaa is right. My original answer was a bit too quick and dirty. It *will* work, but a better solution is either find out where the error class is defined, or make a new custom style. You might want to get in the habit of prefixing your custom styles to avoid this in the future. For instance, if you are developing myawesomewebsite.com, you might rewrite your specified CSS as

```
span.maw_error {
    color: #FF0000; }
```

Comment: Eeeek `!important`. Please just find out what is overruling it.

Comment: Dealing with the specificity of stylesheets can be annoying, to say the least.

Comment: @PeeHaa, you are right. I have edited my answer accordingly. It may not always be feasible, to track down the overriding style, hence the suggestion to prefix his custom classes.

Comment: Edits make this answer MUCH better (css specificity is much better)... however, I maintain that this is not a CSS issue. The php will simply always print `<span class="error"></span><br/>`, so applying a font color won't make any difference.

Comment: @Ben D is right. This was a bad initial answer on my part all around. The PHP Manual says that the empty string and the string "0" evaluate to boolean FALSE, so you were never entering the if($error) code block. I didn't go back and look at the docs for previous PHP versions, but it is always good practice to use real boolean types when you need to test for TRUE/FALSE.